# Can I just copy the snapshot from an existing node to a new machine to restore data？

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

I'm studying backup and restore of Cassandra. The DataStax doc ([Cassandra restore](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html#Restoringfromlocalnodes)) mentioned two ways of restoring data:

1. Restoring from local nodes
2. Restoring from centralized backups.

My question is: Can I just generate the snapshot of my existing node and copy the output files (file.db) to a newly started node. Then put them into the right directory /var/lib/cassandra/data. Is this a right way?

Or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply copy snapshots from one to another because those two nodes won't necessarily own the same token range(s) so the data in the snapshots would be useless to a random node.

In Cassandra, data is distributed across nodes in a cluster, each owning a range of tokens. Each partition (a record) has a partition key (part of the primary key) which is converted into a token value using a hashing algorithm whose value determines which node the partition will be stored.

The SSTables in the snapshot only contain partitions which have token values that lie within the range of tokens owned by a node. Copying the snapshot to a node which owns a different range of tokens means that some or all the partitions in the SSTables will be lost since the new node will never accept reads for partitions it doesn't own.

If you want to restore data to a node with identical configuration (including token ownership), you can use the "refresh method". I've documented the detailed procedure in [How to restore snapshots to a cluster with identical configuration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316497/).

Otherwise, you will need to bulk-load the snapshots using the `sstableloader` utility so the data in the SSTables are sent to the nodes which own them (replicas). I've documented the detailed procedure in [How to clone data to a new cluster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316520/). Cheers!

Comment: Much thanks Erick. I've read your anwser "How to clone data to a new cluster". Please see if my understandings correct: 1. Since snapshot only contains part of whole database, I need to get snapshot of each original node. 2. I need to copy these snapshot to directory keyspace_name/table_name. 3. use sstableloader to load data to dest cluster nodes. I wonder if the nodes in dest cluster should be started or stopped during this procedure, or do I have to node refresh before start?

Comment: It's very helpful, Erick. I can successfully transfer the data to a new cluster following your doc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the missing part is that if the node is not one of the replicas of the token ranges copied, the data in the files is not going to appear. It will be in the files, but the node will not consider that it owns it or responds to queries with it.

If you have 3 nodes with RF3 on a keyspace, it will work, in that all 3 should have the same data on that keyspace.

You also have to run a nodetool refresh, or restart the node for the files to be picked up.

Comment: Thanks andrew. I'm aware of "refresh" part.  But I'm confused with "If you have 3 nodes with RF3 on a keyspace, it will work". You mean if I have 2 nodes in a cluster, then I start a new node. Then I need to reconfig RF2 to RF3. So the new node is able to query the date restored from snapshot?

Comment: Well, I think I understand what you're saying. My current cluster contains 2 nodes and RF2. When I use nodetool status my_keyspace, I found both node owns 100% of the keyspace. So it means when I take a snapshot, it takes the snapshot of all data. Is that correct?